# Using android Room to get the maximum result of another table

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room, android-architecture-components

In the room documentation there is this example of how to use `@Relation` to get all 'Users' and all 'Pets'

```
public class User {
     int id;
     // other fields
 }
 public class PetNameAndId {
     int id;
     String name;
 }
 public class UserAllPets {
   @Embedded
   public User user;
   @Relation(parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "userId", entity = Pet.class)
   public List pets;
 }
 @Dao
 public interface UserPetDao {
     @Query("SELECT * from User WHERE age > :minAge")
     public List<UserAllPets> loadUserAndPets(int minAge);
 }
```

However, if instead of wanting to get all Pets, in this scenario, I just wanted all Users and most recent Pet created, A group by userid.[image]

Would I just filter the results after querying the database, or would it be better to create a foreign key query.